# Angular 6 HttpClient API Requests Not Being Made

Tags: angular, angular6, httpclient, angular2-observables

I have an ApiService in Angular 6 with the following function:

```
 add(data, string: string, type): Observable<Object | Response> {
    return this._http.post(this.url + string, data).pipe(
      tap(() => this.log(`added ${type} successfully`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Response>(`Adding ${type}`))
    );
 }
```

This function is called in a component as follows:

```
this.api.add(this.parent, 'parents/new', 'Parent').subscribe(() => {
 this.authService.login(this.user, 'login').subscribe();
 this.router.navigate(['/register/student']);
});
```

The calls to the api are not firing at all even though I've subscribed to the Observable. Please help me out guys. Thank you

Comment: Does your app navigate to the `/register/student` page?

Comment: No, it doesn't. The function is supposed to add the parent to the DB by making an API call and then log them in via their credentials and then navigate to ```/register/student``` page. Since the the API call isn't being made, it breaks and navigates to the login page

Comment: Do you get any response from your http function ? May be your backend function is frozen and your subscription never emit or catch any error.
Also, I would not call .subscribe() in a subscribe(). Use a higher observable with mergeMap.